# How do I set the position of an Entry Scollbar?

Tags: python, tkinter

In the following program, I display an Entry box that I want to be able to have a scroll bar right under my Entry box.  This works but the scroll bar is at the bottom, not under the Entry box.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
calc = Frame(root)
calc.grid()

def saveIt():
    print(text_box.get())

text_box = Entry(calc, justify=RIGHT, width=20)
text_box.grid(row=1, column = 0, pady = 5)
text_box.insert(0, "testtest1234567890testtest")

scrollbar=Scrollbar(root,orient=HORIZONTAL, command=text_box.xview, width=10)
scrollbar.grid(row=2,  column = 0,sticky=E+W, pady=4)

save_button = Button(calc, text = "save")
save_button["command"] = lambda: saveIt()
save_button.grid(row=3, column = 0, pady = 5)

text_box.config(xscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
root.mainloop()
```

Since I am just starting to learn Python and tkinter, any and all comments (or even solutions to the problem) will be gladly received.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Also, no need for `lambda: saveIt()`. You can (and should) just write `save_button['command'] = saveIt`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the parent widget of `text_box` and `save_button` is `calc`, whose parent is `root`, and the parent of the scroll bar is also `root`. So `calc` as a whole is gridded above the scroll bar, and so everything inside `calc` is above the scroll bar too. You just need to change

```
scrollbar = Scrollbar(root, orient=HORIZONTAL, command=text_box.xview, width=10)
```

to

```
scrollbar = Scrollbar(calc, orient=HORIZONTAL, command=text_box.xview, width=10)
```